# How to assign colors in Blender from an hex code in a JSON file?

Tags: scripting, color

I would like to produce 3D graphs in Blender from coordinates in a JSON file, how can I retrieve the color code from the JSON file to assign to each points it's own color on the graph?
I am using the Blender_Spreadsheet_Import script (on Github) to import my JSON file, but it only recognizes Field Names such as "Float", "Integer" and "Boolean" and the hex code for color (eg. "#CC6633" or just "CC6633") doesn't work.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158896/how-set-hex-in-rgb-node-python?noredirect=1#comment269316_158896